# Barrier between Two Processes

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

I want to create a barrier between two processes. For that purpose, I have used two semaphores. When Process 1 reaches the barrier, it signals Process 2 by posting the first semaphore. Process 2 on receiving the signal, posts the second semaphore as an acknowledgment.

The code looks something like this...

Proc1:

```
sem_post( &sem_sig );
sem_wait( &sem_ack );
```

Proc2:

```
sem_wait( &sem_sig );
sem_post( &sem_ack );
```

Now my question is if this method is the most efficient or is there any better technique to implement process level barriers between two processes?

Answer (score 2):

Linux implements `pthread_barrier_t`. To me it looks like a perfect fit to your needs. For the call to `pthread_barrier_init` you'd just have to specify that this barrier is process shared.

Comment: If I do fork and pthread_barrier_t is there in shared memory, Do I need to call pthread_barrier_init only in parent process or both.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Only in one process.  And you should do it before the `fork()`, so that you can be sure that the second process won't try to access it before it's been initialised.